# "Length must be at least 1 (was -1)" what causes this and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get the error with this line of code:

[image]

This is what `getBackground()` looks like:

```
public class MyClass {

  ...

  private String background;

  public String getBackground() {
    return background;
  }

  ...
}
```

I've verified that `Color.parseColor` takes a string.  Why this is happening, and how I can make the compiler happy?

This doesn't stop the app from running, so perhaps this a static analyzer thing? I tried putting the return value from getBackground() in a local and checking that it was non-null and had `length() >= 1`, but that didn't appear to solve anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty much like the issue with one of the static analyzer inspections. If you pass `String` literal to the `Color#parseColor(String)`, e.g. `Color.parseColor("#eee");` the issue disappears.
Looks like static analyzer isn't smart enough to infer that the value you pass in (which is return value of `getBackground()`) is non-null in all possible cases, thus it shows you that *possibly* this value is `null` or empty. If you're sure that color `String` is non-null you can just suppress it like so:

```
//noinspection ResourceType
view.setColor(Color.parseColor(model.getColor().getBackground()));
```

Answer (score 0):

initilize the string variable with zero, like

```
String x = null;
anyview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(x));
```